# Convert SVG with system fonts to PNG using batik

Tags: java

SVG:[image]
PNG:[image]
When I use Batik to convert SVG to PNG, the Symbol font in SVG is not recognized. Is there any way to add fonts to batik to make them work? Thanks!

Comment: What is the error message (if any) your receive from batik?

Comment: No error is reported, but the font is not displayed. For example, the letter D in the Symbol font is a △, but the transformation does not recognize the Symbol font, so the Symbol displaying the △ in SVG will display the D in the PNG.